# How can I integrate Fragments into ViewModels using MVVMCross

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm new in Xamarin and I'm trying to create my first app. The app will have 4 independent modules with the following functionalities as minimum:
    - List of records.
    - View for creating a new record.
    - References to a global module (profile user).

The point is, I found some tutorials in the web that implements AppCompatActivity, Fragment, Toolbar, ActionBar, so on. The sources can be found here: https://github.com/JoeRock11/Xamarin_DesignLibrary

The example contains three tabs, which have a fragment inside them, and you can slide the screen to change the current tab (similar to facebook). I want to do the same for my app, each tab is one module.

Although the sample works perfectly, I want to implement the MVVMCross framework but I have no idea how to achieve it.

This is an Fragment sample:

```
public class Fragment1 : Fragment 
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment1, container, false) as RecyclerView;
        SetUpRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        return recyclerView;
    }
    private void SetUpRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        var values = GetDataSource();
        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context));
        recyclerView.SetAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerView.Context, values, Activity.Resources));

        recyclerView.SetItemClickListener((rv, position, view) =>
        {
            //Tasks
        });
    }
}
```

This is a ViewModel which implements MVVMCross but work with activities (core project):

```
public class AllPostsViewModel : MvxViewModel 
{
    public List<Post> AllPosts { get; set; }
    public ICommand NavBack
    {
        get {return new MvxCommand(() => Close(this));}
    }
    public void Init()
    {
        Task<List<Bill>> result = Mvx.Resolve<Repository>().GetAllPosts();
        result.Wait();
        AllPosts = result.Result;
    }
}
```

View (Android project)

```
[Activity(Label = "Posts", NoHistory = true)]
public class AllPostsView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View_AllBills);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to change my core and android projects to use Fragments instead of Activities.

Additionally, I would like to know your opinions about use fragments instead of Activities for this particular case, because I just using fragment because the tutorial I read.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by using a ViewPager in your app. **First** create a layout that resembles this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:background="@color/bglight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Second** step is to create a host activity that adds your fragments to the tab and the viewpager. The viewmodel of your activity will host the viewmodels of your fragments as properties. So all your Fragments should inherit from MvxFragment there TViewmodel is the corresponding viewmodel to the fragment. This class can be found in the MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4 Library.

**Third** step will be to add a viewpageradapter that works with MvxFragments. Just add this code to your project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Java.Lang;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4;
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using FragmentManager = Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager;
using String = Java.Lang.String;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter
        : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly Context _context;
        public IEnumerable<FragmentInfo> Fragments { get; private set; }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return Fragments.Count(); }
        }

        public MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter(
            Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, IEnumerable<FragmentInfo> fragments)
            : base(fragmentManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            Fragments = fragments;
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            var fragmentInfo = Fragments.ElementAt(position);
            var fragment = Fragment.Instantiate(_context,
            Java.Lang.Class.FromType(fragmentInfo.FragmentType).Name);
            ((MvxFragment)fragment).ViewModel = fragmentInfo.ViewModel;
            return fragment;
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return new String(Fragments.ElementAt(position).Title);
        }

        public class FragmentInfo
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public Type FragmentType { get; set; }
            public IMvxViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

And **final** step is to wire everything up like this.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.viewpagerlayout);

    var viewPager = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);

    var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo>
    {
        new MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo
        {
            FragmentType = typeof(AccountsTabAccountsView),
            Title = ViewModel.AccountTabTitle,
            ViewModel = ViewModel.AccountsViewModel
        },
        new MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter.FragmentInfo
        {
            FragmentType = typeof(AccountsTabCardsView),
            Title = ViewModel.CardsTabTitle,
            ViewModel = ViewModel.CardsViewModel
        }
    };
    viewPager.Adapter = new MvxViewPagerFragmentAdapter(Activity, SupportFragmentManager, fragments);
    viewPager.SetCurrentItem(0, true);
    viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 2;

    var tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
    tab.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeFixed;
    tab.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;
    tab.FillViewport = true;
    tab.SetSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(Activity, Resource.Color.blue));
    tab.SetTabTextColors(ContextCompat.GetColor(Activity, Resource.Color.divider), ContextCompat.GetColor(Activity, Resource.Color.blue));            
    tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Comment: What is "ViewModel.AccountsViewModel", I set my ViewModel and I get the error "'PostViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context". This is my ViewModel definition: 
public class PostViewModel : MvxViewModel

Comment: i need to show a recyclerview in fragment inside several tabs. this is not working in that case.